# gcc undefined reference to portaudio functions

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors, portaudio

I am trying to use portaudio in one of my projects. Unfortunately, I cannot compile my main.c file.

**Error: "undefined reference to 'Pa_Initialize'"** (Pa_Initialize is a function from the portaudio library)

My working directory includes the .a file from portaudio as well as the portaudio.h.

My current gcc command: **gcc main.c libportaudio.a -lm -o main**

**Update:** these are the includes in my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"
```

Comment: you typically need to include a header that declares the library functions or defines macros, enumerations, etc. You should also use -l<library> to compile with a library. See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: According to the docs, it's #include "portaudio.h"
http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html

Comment: Do not change your question to report that it is solved. Consider making your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by rebuilding the portaudio library.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an *undefined reference* error, you have probably already integrated the header file `portaudio.h`.

As Kurt E. Clothier already mentioned, you must also mention the libraries inside your gcc command. According to [the portaudio website](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html), the gcc command is

```
gcc main.c libportaudio.a -lrt -lm -lasound -ljack -pthread -o main
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change anything